# Why BSC is used more in DeFi apps?

Tags: nft, bsc

I decided to deploy my NFT collectibles in **BSC (Binance Smart Chain)** because of Gas Prices in Ethereum blockchain. So, I researched some Dapps deployed in BSC. I've found that most of the applications are **DeFi** applications like Venus, PancakeSwap, Autofarm etc.

Is there a reason for BSC is mostly used for DeFi apps? What would happen if I deploy my collectible smart contract on BSC?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the lower fees and because of the hype that BNB is experiencing. Those defi applications you mentioned, along with all the clones and scams that you find, are all inflated and if you invest any money you take a big risk to see your funds gone.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with deploying NFT collectibles on BSC.